# YII UserIdentity not being updated per refresh?

Tags: yii

I have:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
  private $_balance;
  public function getBalance()          { return $this->_balance; }
}
```

The problem is, this getBalance value needs to get updated every time the page is refreshed. But it currently only does this when the user logs in the first time. I will have the same problem if a user gets banned, and he is already logged in.

How do I get around this? In other words, how do I force the stored user states to get refreshed every time the user reloads the page?

Here is the code that sets the actual user:

public function authenticate()
  {

```
$api = new api();
$user = $api->getAccountDetailsByCellNr($this->username);

if (empty($user)) {
  $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
}
else {

  if(!isset($this->username))
    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
  else if($user->password !== md5($this->password) )
    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
  else {
    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;

    $this->setState('balance', $user->balance);

  }

}
```

Comment: You don't show the code that actually *sets* the balance. Which is kind of important.

Comment: why not you keep balance in session and update it  in main layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the `init()` function in your WebUser class.
Something like:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
  ...
  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();
    $user = $api->getAccountDetailsByCellNr($this->username);
    $this->_balance = $user->balance;
  }
}
```

Comment: is webUser is initiated on page refresh?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question?